# How to get list of contacts in specific engagement plan state?

Tags: xdb, engagement-plans

I have an engagement plan and there are number of contacts in each state.

How can I programmatically obtain list of contacts which are in specific engagement plan state by state ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have just found a method:

```
var pageableContactIds = AutomationManager.Provider.GetEnrolledContactsIdsByStatePaged(engagementPlanStateId);
```

This will return an object of type `Sitecore.Common.IPageable<ID>` which provides a method `.GetAll()`

Seems to work for me.